# Passing Non-Null Parameter returns NULL records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I had recently posted a question about how to handle NULL values in SQL Server Reporting Services. The question is located at [Handle NULL values in SQL Server Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087095/handle-null-values-in-sql-server-reporting-services).

Applying `WHERE @MyParam=MyCol OR @MyParam IS NULL` faces a problem, which is if I select single NON-NULL value (from the dropdownlist and pass this as in SQL Server), this also brings the NULL value records. It should only bring the Non NULL value's records.

What should be done to avoid NULL records, if NON-NULL records are selected?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an exclusive OR (XOR):

```
-- Exclusive OR is an either/or combination which, 
-- using => as "is defined as" symbol, can be shown as:
-- 
-- x XOR y => (x AND (NOT y)) OR ((NOT x) AND y)

-- x => @MyParam = MyCol  
-- y => @MyParam IS NULL



-- DECLARE @MyParam NVARCHAR(32) = 'MC1,MC2'; -- returns two lines
-- DECLARE @MyParam NVARCHAR(32) = 'MC1';     -- returns one line
   DECLARE @MyParam NVARCHAR(32) =  NULL;     -- returns one line


DECLARE @MyParamXML XML = N'<root><r>' + replace(@MyParam,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

;WITH   SOExample AS
(
    SELECT cast('MC1' AS NVARCHAR(12)) AS MyCol, 'Line 1'    AS MyCol2 UNION ALL
    SELECT      'MC2'                          , 'Line 2'              UNION ALL
    SELECT       NULL                          , 'Line NULL'
)
SELECT * from SOExample 
WHERE
       (@MyParam IS NULL     AND ISNULL(MyCol,'<NULL Value>') = '<NULL Value>') 
    OR (@MyParam IS NOT NULL AND 
        SOExample.MyCol IN 
            (SELECT SSRSlist.MyParams.value('.','NVARCHAR(32)') as MyParam 
             FROM   @MyParamXML.nodes('//root/r') as SSRSlist(MyParams)))
```

Comment: This bring all NON-NULL values correctly but when selecting NULL, it doesn't bring NULL values.It brings 0 rows in that case.

Comment: I'm using IN clause instead of '=' when using MyCol as the values are multi dropdownlist

Comment: Thanks for the inputs but the final edit too doesn't populate records with NULL values in it. It works like a charm for NON-NULL records.

Comment: Moreover, won't the sql query would be 

(ISNULL(MyCol,-9999999) = @MyCol instead of

(ISNULL(MyCol,-9999999) = -99999999

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18788/discussion-between-smith-pascal-jr-and-mceda)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't works. When I'm passing Multiple non-null values, it is fetching NULL values too..

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at the latest version?

Comment: let us continue this discussion in chat (to enter the chat please refer previous link - as mentioned in the above comments)